# Passing an array of objects (custom class) as value and string as key in a map in Hazelcast

Tags: java, collections, hazelcast

In a hazelcast project, I wish to use map or multimap which is bundled in its library, the issue is that I want to map objects of a custom class (say Computer) (that contains 2 string   and 2 integer data items) as values and keeping String as key "Laptop" , "Desktop".

The problem is I am unable to figure out how to use list or array of objects in the map.

Alter: If I try to store objects individually and not as a list or array, how should I code to read those all objects using key as input. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a tour on how ask questions properly. "I am unable to figure out how to use..." is not a real question on a real problem. If you want to learn about maps there are plenty of tutorials around.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.